# Autocomplete of OpenCV functions with Vim

Tags: vim, opencv, autocomplete, vi

Is there a dictionary for OpenCV functions and stuff that could be used with Vim `<Ctrl-x>` autocomplete?

Alternatively, is it possible to configure Vim to find them automatically from the header files of OpenCV? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: What is "autofinish"? In my vim Ctrl-x subtracts one from the number under the cursor. It you meant autocomplete have a look into ctags or clang-complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run ctags (or etags) over the opencv code to create a tags file containing the names (functions, variables, class members, macros etc) present in OpenCV.

Then include the tags file by putting in your .vimrc:

`set tags+=~/.vim/tags/created_opencv_tags_file`

Comment: could you please give some more details about the first step ,How can i create opencv tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely ctags didn't tagged all functions in the OpenCV header files.

Here is a complete tutorial about making it work with Exuberant-ctags.

http://plagatux.es/2009/02/generar-etiquetas-con-ctags-y-usarlas-en-vim/comment-page-1/#comment-1716

It is in spanish but just writing the commands did the job even if I don't know a word in spanish.

Comment: The link is dead.